# private message wont be submitted, js $.post(...) not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, message-system

I would like to have a message system and embed it to my system, but this littel could couldn't proceed! it never post to mysql ... :\

I had some extra conditions in t.php but I didn't merge them here until this part work well because it is the main part.
it's been a month ago that I'm trying to implement message system to be used in our project but because of many minor problems happens I couldn't achieve that.

here is the form file

msgform.php

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    session_start();
    $id = 1; //$_SESSION['id'];
    $q = "SELECT `rname` FROM `reciever` WHERE `sid`=".$id." AND `id`=".$_GET['id'];
    $query = mysql_query($q);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $rname = $row[0];
    $q1 = "SELECT `sname` FROM `senders` WHERE `id`=".$_GET['id'];
    $query1 = mysql_query($q1);
    $count1 = mysql_num_rows($query1);
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_row($query1);
    $sname = $row1[0];
    $ranNum = rand(0, 10);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <tiltle>Testing area at sender</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#msgForm').submit(function(){$('input[type=submit]'), this.altr('disabled', 'disabled');});
            function sendMsg(){
                    var mheader = msgForm.msgHeader.value;
                    var mbody = msgForm.msgBody.value;
                    var sname = msgForm.sname.value;
                    var sid = msgForm.sid.value;
                    var rname = msgForm.rname.value;
                    var rid = msgForm.rid.value;
                    var thisWipit = msgForm.msgWipit.value;
                    var formData = {mheader: mheader, mbody: mbody, sname: sname, sid: sid, rname: rname, rid: rid, thisWipit: thisWipit};
                    $.post('t.php', formData,
                        function (data){
                            $('#tstmsgs').slideUp("slow");
                            $('#sthWrong').html(data).show();
                        }
                    );
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="sthWrong" style="color:#900; margin-right:10%;"></div>
        <div id="tstmsgs">
            <FORM name="msgForm" id="msgForm" method="POST">
                <font size="+1">Sen to<strong><?php echo "$rname"; ?></strong></font><br/>
                Subject:
                <input name="msgHeader" id="msgHeader" type="text" maxlength="64" style="width:98%;"/>
                </br>
                Message:
                <textarea name="msgBody" id="msgBody" rows="8" style="width:98%;"></textarea>
                  <input name="sid" id="sid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>"/>
                  <input name="sname" id="sname" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sname;?>"/>
                  <input name="rid" id="rid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>"/>
                  <input name="rname" id="rname" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rname;?>"/>
                  <input name="msgWipit" id="msgWipit" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ranNum;?>"/>
                  <input name="msgSubmit" type="submit" value="send" onClick="sendMsg();"/>
            </FORM>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the handler page

t.php

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    $mheader = $_POST['mheader'];
    $mbody = $_POST['mbody'];
    $sname = $_POST['sname'];
    $sid = $_POST['sid'];
    $rname = $_POST['rname'];
    $rid = $_POST['rid'];
    $thisWipit = $_POST['thisWipit'];
    $sessWipit = base64_decode('1');

    if ((isset($mheader) && !empty($mheader)) && (isset($mbody) && !empty($mbody)) && (isset($sid) && !empty($sid)) && (isset($rid) && !empty($rid)) && (isset($sname) && !empty($sname)) && (isset($rname) && !empty($rname)) && (isset($thisWipit) && !empty($thisWipit)))
    {
        $to = $rid;
        $from = $sid;
        $toName = $rname;
        $fromName = $sname;
        $sub = $mheader;
        $msg = $mbody;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `msgs` (`sid`, `rid`, `time_sent`, `msgbody`, `msgheader`) VALUES ('$from', '$to', NOW(), '$msg', '$sub')";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$query) echo "Database Error : ".$sql;
        echo 'Messgae sent successfully.';
    }

    else
    {

        if((isset($mheader) && empty($mheader)))
            echo '- Please fill out the Subject field.<br/>';

        if((isset($mbody) && empty($mbody)))
            echo '- Please fill out the Message field.<br/>';

        if((isset($sid) && empty($sid)) || (isset($rid) && empty($rid)) || (isset($sname) && empty($sname)) || (isset($rname) && empty($rname)) || (isset($thisWipit) && empty($thisWipit)))
            echo '- Some data are missed.<br/>';
}



?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at your development console (firebug or equivalent) to see if there are errors? If there really is no post, then PHP is irrelevant to the problem (less clutter is easier to debug). For submitting form values, try using [$(..).serialize()](http://api.jquery.com)/serialize/). The first line of the script has multiple problems, try `$('#msgForm').on('submit', function(evt){$('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', 'disabled');});` And you probably want to prevent the form from being submitted the regular way, or it'll be send twice.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I wanted from that line "And you probably want to prevent the form from being submitted the regular way, or it'll be send twice." I'm using a development console and it didnt show any error. I tried your line but it didnt work too, thdnk you